# Trying to get this conditional to work. How do I get this variable to be set?

Tags: jsf, trinidad

I am trying to conditionally set this variable so I don't have to display date slashes when I display an empty entry.

```
  <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${fn:length(findYear[1]) eq 0}">...</c:when>
    <c:set var="dateformat" value="fn:length(findYear[1]) " />
    <c:when test="${fn:length(findYear[1]) gt 0}">
      <c:set var="dateformat" value="${findYear[1]} / ${findYear[2]} / ${findYear[0]}" />
    </c:when>
  </c:choose>

  <tr:column  width="71px" align="center" headerText="Date" sortable="true" sortProperty="type">
    <tr:outputText value= "${dateformat}">
      <!--  "${findYear[1]} / ${findYear[2]} / ${findYear[0]}"  readOnly= "true"  > -->
    </tr:outputText>​
```

Right now, nothing is showing up when I call the variable. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work with a plain simple `h:outputText` without a `tr:column` and more? And what **does** happen? Oh and the first `c:set` is between two `c:when` lines. That cannot work...!

Comment: Yeah. It works when I just give it the output. The only problem is that if those substrings are empty, it will then just display "//" instead of a date if there is nothing. No matter what string I use, it always wants to evaluate the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test="${empty findYear[1]}">
    <c:set var="dateformat" value="${findYear[0]}" />
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>
    <c:set var="dateformat" value="${findYear[1]} / ${findYear[2]} / ${findYear[0]}" />
  </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

- The `empty` operator returns `true` when the argument is `null` or empty string.
- The first `<set>` statement was outside of any `<when>` block, and its value did not contain `${}`...
- As your conditions complete one another, `<otherwise>` could be used.